# RecyclerView Limit to Maximum Records

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

Here is what I achieved ? **3 sections** (`i.e.` Section 1, Section 2 and Section 3), where `each section` contains *10 items* and the tutorial [link](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html) I am following

Now, Here is the requirement

**Section 1:**

`ALREADY DONE` I want to show Horizontal Items

`PENDING` Limit to 5 Records only (but getting all 10)

**Section 2:**

`ALREADY DONE` I want to show Grid Items

`PENDING` Limit to 2 Rows and 2 Cols = 4 Records only (but getting all 10)

**Section 3:**

`ALREADY DONE` I want to show Vertical Items

`PENDING` Limit to 5 Records only (but getting all 10)

*MAIN CONCERN: How to limit the Records ?*

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

            ....

            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

             ....
             itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2));

            .....
            itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        }

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to go with heterogeneous recyclerview.
for

section 1) you have a recyclerView with horizonatl scroll

section 3)
change  **LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL to LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL**

```
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new      
    LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
```

section 2)

```
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new     GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
```

Create a separate xml file for each section type
 and *inflate them regarding section type*

1) Horizontal scrolling

2) one for gridview

Or you can create separate recyclerView for gridtype

Comment: Already achieved... main concern is How to limit the Records ?

Comment: what do you return in getItemCount()?

Comment: you should get length of items in every section  so have a if else loop return different value in getItemCount() for different section.

Comment: glad i could help you  :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Main activity

**Horizontal**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

**Vertical**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
```

**GridView**

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**GridView with Horizontal view**

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new
            GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Comment: Already achieved... main concern is How to limit the Records ?